# Error while invoking a stored procedure from java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have written a following stored procedure in a `postgres` database

```
create or replace function reviseTax(revisiondate date, taxrate decimal) returns         table(employeeid integer, month date, difference decimal) AS $$
declare
    thisrow record;
    newTaxAmt decimal;
    differenceAmt decimal;
begin 
for thisrow in select * from employee_salary where salarydate >= revisiondate loop
    newTaxAmt = thisrow.income * $2;
    differenceAmt = newTaxAmt - thisrow.tax;
    update employee_salary es set tax = newTaxAmt where es.employeeid = thisrow.employeeid;
    insert into taxrevision (employeeid , month , difference) values (thisrow.employeeid , thisrow.salarydate , differenceAmt);

end loop;
return query select * from taxrevision as something;
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

This works fine when invoked from the data base.
The problem is when I invoke this stored procedure from java using JDBC code

My java code is as follows

```
System.out.println("Enter the effective date(yyyy-mm-dd) for the tax revision");
dateString = scanner.next();
float newTaxRate = 0.3F;

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
df.setLenient(false);
java.util.Date utilDate = df.parse(dateString);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

CallableStatement callable = DBConnection.prepareCall("{call revisetax(?,?)}");
callable.setDate(1,sqlDate);
callable.setFloat(2,newTaxRate);
callable.executeQuery();
DBConnection.commit();
```

I am getting the following error :

```
ERROR: function revisetax(unknown, real) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add             explicit type casts.
  Position: 14
```

I am not able to figure out why, please help!

Comment: You have to use `CallableStatement`.

Comment: dear jeebus, please tell me this doesn't actually do financial calculations in the real world.  Because if it does let me know what company so I never use them.  For anyone who is wondering I am referring to the use of FLOATS

Comment: This is not any real world calculation! I was trying out a simplified version of a prototype. Thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!! The problem was with the decimal data type in the stored procedure header

```
create or replace function reviseTax(revisiondate date, taxrate decimal) returns         table(employeeid integer, month date, difference decimal) AS $$
```

declare

instead of `decimal` i used `real` and it worked!!

so the function header should have been

```
create or replace function reviseTax(revisiondate date, taxrate real) returns         table(employeeid integer, month date, difference decimal) AS $$
```

declare

P.S. instead of `real` , `double precision` also works

Comment: if you want to use decimal then you have to use the   setBigDecimal(String parameterName, BigDecimal x) method for CallableStatement

Comment: Oh.. dint know that!! Thanks!! I will experiment with that.

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke a stored procedure / function in the database you want to use the `CallableStatement` object.

```
CallableStatement callable = new CallableStatement("{call my_function(?)}");
```

Take note to the curly braces within the callable statement.

Comment: I have replaced PreparedStatement with CallableStatement, even then the same error! :(

Comment: @codeMan Please edit your original question with the new code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

use this one

```
 call reviseTax(?,?)
```